# Python tcp socket client

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, tcp, twisted

I need to have a tcp socket client connected to a server to send data and receive. 
But this socket must be always on and i cannot open another socket.

I have always some data to send over the time and then later process the answer to the data sent previously.

If i could open many sockets, i think it was more easy. But in my case i have to send everything on the same socket asynchronously.

So the question is, what do you recommend to use within the Python ecosystem? (twisted, tornado, etc)
Should i consider node.js or another option?

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice to keep your socket online, why can't you just get the data process it in another section and open a socket again?

Comment: I will try to explain. This is a requirement of the server. This server process commands and sends back the answers. When i open a new connection i need to identify myself with an ID (and i only have one ID available to me). I can only have one socket connection with this ID at any given time. I'm trying to figure what is the best way to send a lot of commands and process the answers.

Comment: it sounds like the server you are communicating with defines a protocol on top of TCP.  can you explain a bit more about the server program you are using?

Comment: @dequestarmappartialsetattr i only have that spec. I don't have access to the server software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend Twisted for this:

- It comes with out-of-the-box support for many TCP protocols.
- It is easy to maintain a single connection, there is a `ReconnectingClientFactory` that will deal with disconnections and use exponential backoff, and `LoopingCall` makes it easy to implement a heartbeat.
- Stateful protocols are also easy to implement and intermingle with complex business logic.
- It's fun.

I have a service that is exactly like the one you mention (single login, stays on all the time, processes data).  It's been on for months working like a champ.

Twisted is possibly hard to get your head around, but the tutorials [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/) are a great start.  Knowing Twisted will get you far in the long run!

Comment: Interesting. You send and receive data asynchronously? Do you use any kind of throttle to send?

Comment: @balsagoth: Yes. I have one server that I send data/receive results and I distribute results to a variety of clients that subscribe.  Twisted especially shines when dealing with multiple things happening at the same time, routing, etc (business logic).  I don't do any throttling, but there is a `ThrottlingFactory` that is trivially easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

*"i have to send everything on the same socket asynchronously"*

Add your data to a queue, have a separate thread taking items out of the queue and sending via [`socket.send()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send)